# (when i enter input '(2,we,we,2,30.0)'i have error com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-error-1064

i have an error when i enter the input '(2,we,we,2,30.0)', and it is called as syntax error .i believe that the error comes from create table but cannot identify the error.

here is the code for create table:

```
public  boolean addFlight(Flight flightObj)
    {
        Statement st;
        try {
            st = DB.getConnection().createStatement();
        
        
        String str= "INSERT INTO flight table ("+flightObj.getFlightId()+","+flightObj.getSource()+","+flightObj.getDestination()+","
                     +flightObj.getNoOfSeats()+","+flightObj.getFlightFare()+")";
                            
        try {
            int rowsInserted = st.executeUpdate(str);
            
            if(rowsInserted >0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
```

here is the error code : i think maybe the error comes from create table method

```
hu Sep 10 10:28:56 SGT 2020 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(2,we,we,2,30.0)' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:403)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3933)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3869)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2675)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2465)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1536)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2585)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1464)
    at Zaroflightsystem.FlightManagementSystem.addFlight(FlightManagementSystem.java:22)
    at Zaroflightsystem.Main.main(Main.java:25)
```

Comment: You should add single quotes ' between String. (2,'we','we',2,30.0).

And you should at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement for your queries.

Comment: if i enter the input and want to get the iput,do i need to do  prepared statement?

Comment: Prepared statement has multiple benefits like performance and prevention against SQL injection attacks.